# groupby and store as dictionary string in hive

Tags: sql, hive

So, I have a table as

```
 user_id, product, price
  12, foobar, 1.2
  12, foo, 2.2
  13, baz, 2
  14, biz, 20
  14, buzz, 21
  and so on..
```

I want to group by user id and basically store as following schema

```
schema:
  user_id int, 
  product_prices string
```

and the result be

```
12\t foobar,1.2\tfoo,2.2
13\t baz,2
14\t biz,20\tbuzz,21
```

and so on

How do i do this in hive (sqlish)?

Comment: The requested format is not clear. What are you doing with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with CTE ,CONCAT and concat_ws

Try Below code

```
with temp as
( select user_id, CONCAT(product , ',' , cast(price as String)) res from your_table)

SELECT user_id, concat_ws("\t",collect_set(res))
FROM temp  
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Step 1 CONCAT product and price with "," .

Step 2 Use concat_ws for "\t" to CONCAT array set .

Answer (score 2):

```
select      user_id
           ,concat_ws('\t',collect_list(concat_ws(',',product,cast(price as string))))
from        mytable
group by    user_id
;
```

---

```
+----+----------------------+
| 12 | foobar,1.2   foo,2.2 |
| 13 | baz,2                |
| 14 | biz,20   buzz,21     |
+----+----------------------+
```

... and if dictionary (map) is really what you want:

```
select      user_id
           ,str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat_ws(':',product,cast(price as string)))))
from        mytable
group by    user_id
;
```

---

```
+----+------------------------------+
| 12 | {"foobar":"1.2","foo":"2.2"} |
| 13 | {"baz":"2"}                  |
| 14 | {"biz":"20","buzz":"21"}     |
+----+------------------------------+
```